# how to show/get active directory user lockout status with c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I'm putting together a simple winform to show user AD attributes.

Current info in the form is showing with the following:

```
if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value != null)
phoneTB.Text = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
```

I tried doing this but complains about operands of type object and int

```
if (rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lockoutTime"].Value >= 0)
  acctstatlbl.Text = "Account Locked";
else
  acctstatlbl.Text = "Account Unlocked";
```

Comment: Well… I am guessing that the code… `rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lockoutTime"].Value` … is returning an `Object` and it needs to be cast to the proper type for the comparison to work. I am guessing from the name `lockoutTime` that the object is either a `DateTime` or `Timespan` object, but this is a guess without more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved with the following:**

```
            object largeInteger = rs.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["lockoutTime"].Value; // it's a large integer so we need to get it's value by a little bit complex way
        long highPart = (int)largeInteger.GetType().InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);
        long lowPart = (int)largeInteger.GetType().InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null);
        long result = (long)((uint)lowPart + (((long)highPart) << 32));
        if (result == 0)
        {
            acctstatlbl.Text = "Account Not Locked";
            acctstatPanel.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4CAF50");
        }
        else
        {
            acctstatlbl.Text = "Account Locked";
            acctstatPanel.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E53935");
        }
```

Comment: Actually this bit works but also crashes the program.